# How to represent Array In desired format in java

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I am getting array values as follows in JSP servlet page.

```
String[] JsonEvents = request.getParameterValues("events[]");
```

I just want to know how to change it to the following type.(Lets say "Apple" and "Orange" are the element of received Array)

```
String[] JsonEvents = new String[] { "Apple", "Orange" };
```

Please help me.

Comment: "I just want to know how to change it to the following type." But the type of both expressions is `String[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those are already the same "type" - they are String arrays.

If you want, you can do something like this:

```
String[] JsonEvents = new String[] { 
    request.getParameterValues("events[]")[0], 
    request.getParameterValues("events[]")[1]};
```

but this will throw an exception if there are not at least two parameters, and it will ignore all but the first two.